# Download a file from web on server using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal

Is there a way to download a file on the server accessible via SSH. The problem is that the file size is big, downloading on the client and transfering to server may not work as the connectivity with the server can fail often.

I know the question may mostly have the answer as NO, still any answer would be helpful. I'm not looking for a sudo apt-get.

Comment: you can start `screen` inside `ssh` session and use `wget`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it, both of them will need a consistent connection to transfer the file.

You can use these mechanism for transfer from directly one machine to another no need to do any kind of intermediate downloading and uploading.

Methods are:

1. [scp  (over SSH)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles)

   `scp someuser@someserver:/home/someuser/some.file downloadas.file`
2. [wget (over HTTP/HTTPS)](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

   `wget http://someserver.com/somepath/some.file  -O downloadas.file`

Simply openup your target machine and launch a terminal and issue any of the above command assuming someserver is your source machine from where you need to copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using private key to access your remote server, the command is like this:

```
scp -i PrivateKey.pem ubuntu@your.ip.v4.address:/home/ubuntu/FILENAME.sql ~/Downloads/new.sql
```

here */home/ubuntu/FILENAME.sql* is your remote server file name, *~/Downloads/new.sql* is your local device's file name.

Answer (score 0):

Use scp to download a file from web server:

```
scp -r username@server_ip:/file/path/on/server /destination/file/path
```

Suppose that you want to download /home/ginu(your username)/abc.txt from example.com to /Downloads/abc.txt(destination) and your command on local terminal is:

```
scp -r ginu@example.com:/home/ginu/abc.txt /Downloads/abc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides `scp` you can use `rsync`, which allows you to do partial copies when the file(s) are huge and the connection inconsistent.

You'll find useful information on how to use it (similar to scp) in its man page via `man rsync`.
This [super user thread](https://superuser.com/questions/153176/how-to-rsync-a-large-file-with-as-little-cpu-and-bandwidth-expense-as-possible) is discussing how to use `--partial` and other parameters of `rsync` to copy huge files via an ssh connection.